# How do I copy the name of a repository from Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

I am using Azure DevOps with the version "AzureDevOpsServer_20221122.1".

I have created a repository.

The question sounds clumsy, but I want to copy the name of the repo I created from Azure DevOps.

Is there a context menu for this which I may have overlooked?

If not, what is the best way to copy the repository name without just typing it out?

I want to avoid typing the repository name incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

firstly, go to the azure devops organization

`https://dev.azure.com/<organization>/<project>`, click on the Repos:

[image]

Then choose repo and double click aside the repo name, when the repo name is highlighted press Ctrl+c to copy repo name:

[image]